# Running Matlab script on startup

Tags: matlab, startup

I want to run a Matlab script every time Matlab opens. I cannot, however, use the startup file as our company does not allow us access to our C: drive (yes I know it's very annoying).

I was reading [this MathWorks page](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html) which shows the below example, I am wondering if it is possible to specify a function that does not reside in the startup folder?

> This example runs the MATLAB results script or function after startup, where results.m is in the startup folder or on the MATLAB search path
>
> ```
>    "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin\matlab.exe" -r "results"
> ```

Comment: A solution (probably not feasible) to specify an arbitrary script to be run on startup is to edit the `matlabrc.m`  file

Comment: Like the documentation states, `startup.m` can be anywhere on the [search path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html). I'm assuming you have write access to at least one of the folders in your path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html), `startup.m` can be anywhere on the path.

> Create a startup.m file in a folder **on the MATLAB search path**. Add commands you want executed at startup.

Typically, it can be found in your Documents folder, which you can surely access...

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\MATLAB\startup.m
```

There must be *somewhere* you have write access to on your machine... you can set the initial path for Matlab (on startup) in the [General Preferences](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/preferences.html#brjh09y-3), then place `startup.m` in that location (so it will definitely be on your path), and let it call any script you want.

---

Alternatively, you could add a shortcut to have a 1-click solution, which can be run any time (including immediately after startup). See the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/create-matlab-shortcuts-to-rerun-commands.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you have permissions to set an environment variable.  You can set `MATLABPATH` to contain a path that you do have access to.

[See Set the MATLABPATH Environment Variable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/add-folders-to-matlab-search-path-at-startup.html)

Example:

```
set MATLABPATH=c:\matlab_files\myfolder1;c:\matlab_files\myfolder2
```

Replacing "c:\" with the directories/dives you have access to.  Then you should be able to run as you have listed in your questions.

```
"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin\matlab.exe" -r "results"
```